# Asignar valores a un array multidimensional mediante bucle for

Tags: java, array

Buenas, estoy haciendo un tablero de juego (un hundir la flota simple), y para definir las casillas estoy empleando un 'array' multidimensional (x,y). La idea es inicialmente asignar valores a estas casillas en función del contenido (wáter=0 boat=1), me parece demasiado bruto asignar los valores uno a uno, especialmente de cara a complicar el tipo de ejercicio en el futuro, así que se me ocurre utilizar un bucle 'For' para asignárselos, ¿Debería cubrir con un 'for' todas las casillas y después abrir bucles secundarios para las casillas en las que sí haya un barco?

```
package HundirFlota;

class MyDesk {
    int [][] barcosvivos;

    public MyDesk(){
        this.barcosvivos = new int[5][5];}      

    public MyDesk (int enemydesk[][]){
        this.barcosvivos = new int [5][5];}
}
//Boats life: 0-Water, 1-Life Position, 
/*
 * [0][0][0][0][0]
   [1][0][1][1][1]
   [1][0][0][0][0]
   [1][0][0][0][0]
   [0][0][0][0][0]
*/
```

La duda es cual sería la manera más limpia de hacerlo. Un saludo

Comment: Explica si el modo en el que quieres inicializar la matriz es como la que muestras en tu pregunta. Solo por observación, tu segundo constructor no tiene razón de ser, ya que no usas `enemydesk[][]` dentro del mismo, sin embargo inicializas (igual que en el anterior) el arreglo `barcosvivos`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En Java, cuando inicializas un arreglo, sus casillas contendrán un valor por defecto que depende del tipo de dato del que sea el arreglo. En el caso de `int[][]`, el valor por defecto para `int` es `0`, por lo que al realizar esto:

```
this.barcosvivos = new int[5][5];
```

Tu arreglo almacenado en `barcosvivos` ya se encontrará con todas las casillas inicializadas con valor `0`. Esto lo puedes comprobar con el siguiente código:

```
for (int[] interno : this.barcosvivos) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(interno));
}
```

Que imprimirá:

```
[0][0][0][0][0]
[0][0][0][0][0]
[0][0][0][0][0]
[0][0][0][0][0]
[0][0][0][0][0]
```

Lo que debes hacer es inicializar solo aquellas casillas con los valores que quieras, como 1, 2 o el que convenga más a tu situación. Lo mejor, para tu caso, sería indicar la ubicación (x,y) y orientación (vertical u horizontal) de cada bote y así luego utilizar un ciclo `for` para colocar los datos de cada bote en tu tablero.

Comment: Resuelto, muchas gracias, contando con los valores por defecto me ha evitado tener que asignar los valores de `casilla vacía ` .